# Azure pipeline from Yaml hosted on Gitlab

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, yaml, azure-pipelines

I think it isn't possible to create an Azure Pipeline from Yaml when hosting the Git repository in GitLab. Is anyone able to confirm or deny this?

I think it is possible for GitHub, BitBucket and Azure Repos Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops) the YAML supported only in Azure Repos Git, Bitbucket Cloud, GitHub and GitHub Enterprise Server:

[image]

Comment: That doc page is well hidden :)